# RXJS: How to cancel a Subscription in Ionic 3/Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In Ionic 2/3, I'm calling an HTTP post request, something like this.  This works.  But how do I cancel it?  Some places online say to use `postObservable.unsubscribe()`, but there is no such function.  Any ideas?

```
postObservable:Observable<Response> = null;
```

...

```
this.postObservable = this.http.post(url, data, options);

this.postObservable.subscribe(
    (data) => {
        // do something here
    },
    (data) => {
        // do something here
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you *subscribe* to an observable, it returns a `Subscription` instance. You can then use that subscription to cancel the request:

```
// Imports
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

// ...

this.postObservable = this.http.post(url, data, options);

let subcriber: Subscription = this.postObservable.subscribe(
    (data) => {
        // do something here
    },
    (error) => {
        // handle the error
    });
```

To cancel use this:

```
subscriber.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: I've added a brief description to your answer, hope you don't mind @Melchia :)

Comment: Not at all, the new object is indeed a subscription. Thank you :)